# Prioritizing Jobs on Sun Grid Engine Queue

Tags: queue, sungridengine

I have a bunch of jobs lined up for processing on a Sun Grid Engine queue, but I have just submitted a new job that I would like to prioritize. (The new job is 163981 in the left-most column.) Is there a command I can run to ask the server to process the 163981 job next, rather than the next job in the 140522 job array? I would be grateful for any advice others can offer on this question.

[image]

Comment: Do you have admin access to the cluster? If queue is configured to allow priority to be altered you can use the `-p` option: http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html

Comment: Many thanks, @Vince. Unfortunately, I don't have admin rights :/ . Is there a way to change the relative priority of my own jobs without admin rights?

Answer (score 4):

With admin/manager access you could use:

```
qalter -p <positive number up to 1024>
```

[job id of the job you want to run sooner]

Without admin/manager access you could use:

```
qalter -p <negative numeber down to -1023>
```

[job id of the other job you don't want to run next]

These may not work depending on how long a lag time between when the older job was submitted and the current time and how much weight the administrator has put on the waiting time.

Another option without admin/manager access would be to put the job you don't want to run on hold.

```
qalter -h u <job id of the job you don't want to run now>
```

This will make the job you want to run be the only one eligible. Once it has started running you can remove the hold on the other job with

```
qalter -h U <job id>
```

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the priority for all of your other jobs in one command?

Answer (score 1):

Does changing the job share (`-js` option of `qsub`) accomplish what you want?

Assuming other jobs are running and in queue with `-js` value of 0 (default), submit new job with higher priority like so:

```
qsub -js 10 high_priority.sh
```

Source: http://www.lifesci.dundee.ac.uk/services/lsc/services/cluster/using-cluster